# Need to find a way to calculate the G pixel percentage

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, hsv

I need to calculate the amount of green pixels in a given picture for a project.

I already found a way to generate the green part of a image. Just need to find a way to calculate the green percentage of the given image. And how do you loop it for a image directory?

Here's the codes that I have gathered. Please help me to get the green pixel in the selected saturated area percentage.

```
 import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np

    img = cv2.imread('Image')

    grid_RGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
    dimensions = img.shape

    # height, width, number of channels in image
    height = img.shape[0]
    width = img.shape[1]
    channels = img.shape[2]
 
    print('Image Dimension    : ',dimensions)
    print('Image Height       : ',height)
    print('Image Width        : ',width)
    print('Number of Channels : ',channels)

    # area is calculated as “height x width” 
    area = height * width 
  
    # display the area 
    print("Area of the image is : ", area)

    plt.imshow(grid_RGB) # Printing the original picture after converting to RGB

   grid_HSV = cv2.cvtColor(grid_RGB, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV) # Converting to HSV
   lower_green = np.array([25,52,72])
   upper_green = np.array([102,255,255])

   mask= cv2.inRange(grid_HSV, lower_green, upper_green)
   res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask) # Generating image with the green part

   print("Green Part of Image")
   plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
   plt.imshow(res)


  # Load image and convert to HSV
  im = Image.open('.image').convert('HSV')

  # Extract Hue channel and make Numpy array for fast processing
  Hue = np.array(im.getchannel('H'))

  # Make mask of zeroes in which we will set greens to 1
  mask = np.zeros_like(Hue, dtype=np.uint8) 

  # Set all green pixels to 1
  mask[(Hue>80) & (Hue<90)] = 1 

  print(mask.mean()/100 * area/100)
  # Now print percentage of green pixels
  print((mask.mean()*100))
  print((mask.mean()*mask.size)/100)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following method is not so accurate but it does the job quite well. You may find the entire source code [here](https://github.com/tanishqvyas/GreeneryEstimator)

```
green_pixel_count = 0
TOTAL_PIXELS = 1024 # Some dummy value 

# Find green pixel count for each sector
for i in img:
    for j in i:

        if(j[1]>j[0] and j[1]>j[2] and j[0]<100 and j[2]<100):
            green_pixel_count += 1

greenery_percentage = green_pixel_count*100/TOTAL_PIXELS
```

Comment: Just a question, how do I use your codes to calculate the saturated picture?

Comment: As I said it is not 100% accurate. I used this method to calculate percentage greenery for satellite images. Where the saturation hardly varied much. Thus it worked quite well.